# What is repeat until success strategy?

Tags: quantum-algorithms

What is repeat until success strategy? Is it related to post-selection ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A repeat until success (RUS) strategy is a strategy that you retry or extend until it succeeds.

You could think of postselection as a type of RUS, but postselection is very inefficient because the only way to retry it is to throw away and restart the entire computation even if that means hours or years more work to get back to the current point. Good RUS constructions have a retry cost that's very low. For example, if you're attempting to phase a qubit by some angle T, and you are using a RUS strategy, it will either work or you will end up phasing by the wrong angle so you now have to correct that by phasing the qubit by some angle T'.

Comment: How do you know how much you phased it by, without measuring?

Comment: @MarkS The protocol will always have a measurement of some sort that heralds success or failure.

Comment: Oh now I see. You don’t destroy the superposition in a meaningful way to learn how much you overshot or undershot T.